# demoiselle-jsf-parent - problema com escopo/sessão

Tags: demoiselle

Eu estou com um problema com uma aplicação desenvolvida com Demoiselle e acredito que esteja relacionado ao escopo do ManagedBean.

Fiz o teste na aplicação de exemplo (Bookmark) e ocorreu o mesmo problema (somente criei o projeto baseado no demoiselle-jsf-parent e executei).

Quando abro o mesmo registro (tela de edição) em duas janelas do navegador (mesmo navegador e mesma sessão) e volto para a primeira aba clicando em salvar parece que o sistema perde a referencia ao MB criando uma nova instância ao invés de atualizar.

Vou descrever como simular o problema para que alguém possa me ajudar a entende-lo:

1. Execute a aplicação Bookmark;
2. Acesse a listagem;
3. Copie o link da URL e cole em uma nova aba.
4. Volte para a primeira aba e acesse um registro;
5. Vá na segunda aba e acesse o mesmo registro;
6. Volte para a primeira aba e clique em salvar (aqui ocorre o erro, inclusive quando ocorre o update o botão excluir é removido deixando somente o salvar, se clicar em salvar o registro é duplicado);

Qual a melhor maneira de resolver este problema?